# how do i trigger search with the enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, keydown

i need to trigger search with the enter key but its not working, this is the code i used. any help will be appreciated.

```
 $('#header input[name=\'search\']').bind('click', function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {

        url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

        var search = $('input[name=\'search\']').attr('value');

        if (search) {
            url += '&search=' + encodeURIComponent(search);
        }

        location = url;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you most likely want to catch the keyup event and not click

```
 $('#header input[name=\'search\']').bind('keyup', function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log("FOOOOOO");
        url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

        var search = $('input[name=\'search\']').attr('value');

        if (search) {
            url += '&search=' + encodeURIComponent(search);
        }
        console.log("url: "+url);
        window.location.href  = url;
    }
});
```

i dont know what youre try to achive but i would code this selector :

```
$('#header input[name="search"]')...
```

updated

```
// 
$('input[name="search"]').bind("enterKey",function(e){
   console.log("yeah i just triggered");
});


$('input[name="search"]').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
});
```

Comment: what is not working, check my updated example, does the browser console log "FOOOOOO" ?  what does it log for "url:  ?

Comment: i rather think you have some errors in console, or this doesnt work :  url = $('base').attr('href')

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, you'd better use

```
<input type="submit" value="">
```

wrap inputs into a `<form>`

and stylize button

```
input[type='submit'] {height: 0; width: 0; overflow: hidden;}
```

If you need to change action url in javascript, use something like

```
$('form').submit ( function() {
    $(this).attr('action','/route-to-submit');
})
```

Comment: @elmage you already have the `<div class="button-search" title="Search"></div>` element, the only thing you need to do is to change `div` to `<input type="submit">` as i commented above.

Comment: @elmage change `<div class="button-search" title="Search"></div>` to
`<input class="button-search" type="submit" value="">` 
and wrap inputs into a `<form action="/index.php?route=product/search"> ... </form>`

Comment: @elmage first of all, your action url is very-very bad. use relative path `action="/index.php?route=product/search"`, **do not include the domain name**

Comment: @elmage and also comment your js-code to make sure that it doesn't corrupt everything (btw, the domain in action attribute can be inserted by your js)